# Is there any book for chemistry which has all the reactions in it ? A book of just reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

Is there any book for chemistry which has all the reactions in it ? A book of just reactions. I have gone through way too many but each just explains the types of reaction and to get all the reactions collected at once place will take too long. So there any book which has all the reactions listed?

Comment: Not. We don't have enough trees

Comment: Any such book would be out of date before it was even printed with current rate of publication by the world's chemists.

Comment: @Waylander, There should another book highlighting the fake organic yields. Too much junk in the synthetic literature. Biochemistry / medical reproducibility research needs another treatise.

Comment: The ongoing Compendium of Organic Synthetic Methods is the closest thing I know of, but still far short of all reactions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such heavenly book that contains all the reactions known to humanity; however, two databases are worth mentioning which summarize most of the published chemical reactions. One is Reaxys of Elsevier, and the other is SciFinder.

Reaxys includes not only the recent literature, but the nice thing is that it has data from the monstrous *Gmelin Handbuch der Anorganischen Chemie* (Handbook of Inorganic Chemistry), *Beilstein's Handbuch der Organischen Chemie* (Handbook of Organic Chemistry), all the reaction summaries published in organic/inorganic literarture, and patents. One can only be awed by the German contributions to chemical encyclopedias-like collections and writings which started in the early 1800s. In the previous century, the French tried translating Beilstein to keep up with the organic synthetic literature but gave it up as a hopeless exercise. Who would translate thousands of pages every year? As a result, many English-speaking organic chemists had to learn German until recently. By recent, I mean until the 1990s.

The second database is SciFinder of the Chemical Abstract Service (USA). It contains a relatively recent set of reactions (limited to the 1900s, if I remember correctly) from all published literature and world patents. Finally, however, another service called SciFinder${^n}$. It includes hundreds of thousands of abstracts from *Chemische Zentralblatt*, the German abstracting service from pre-1900 works. But, of course, these databases consist of millions of pages if you were to compile a book and are beyond the range of personal purchases. Moreover, SciFinder summarizes from more than ten languages.

Many Russian books summarize inorganic reactions; these books were discussed here in SE Chemistry some time ago (please add the name).

Comment: These databases are, of course, not free.

Answer (score 1):

Organic Chemistry: 100 Must-Know Mechanisms by Roman Valiulin is the closest thing I can think of. Otherwise, pick up Clayden's Organic Chemistry or Bruice's Organic Chemistry and make your own list.

What is this for ? There's also databases of organic transformations for cheminformatics purpouses but nothing is even close to being complete (if it will ever be).